# Does bounty need some protection

Tags: discussion, bounty, accepted-answer, wrong-answers

I have bounty on a question: <strike>no-link</strike>.

On the last day of the bounty, someone answered it of something ain't fix it as I asked.

Like if you ask How to fix something ...
Then you get answer you can't fix it, so do it without fixing and it will work!

I used to comment his answer trying to explain I know that and this I didn't ask about.

This situation lets me have some questions.

- What if  he gets score 2, will he gets the half with wrong answer?
- What if someone answered it before 2 or 1 minutes and he gets 2 up-votes by creating some accounts?will he get half rep points?
- Shouldn't the bounty questions get some kind of protection like no one can vote-up answers lower than 100 reputation (as an example)?

Comment: There is a protection, no one can upvote an answer unless the user has 15 reputations points. And you can always downvote so making it a bit difficult for automatic bounty award.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bounty you give out is not given for you to get a better answer (necessarily). You offer a bounty to attract more answers to your question.

The rep you "pay" when you offer a bounty is the "cost" of it getting a lot more attention.

There are no systems in place to prevent a bounty being awarded because you (the OP) aren't the only factor taken into account, but also the general usefulness of the answers you were given.

If someone told you "You don't need to fix it" or "You're doing it wrong entirely", and it was upvoted many times, it's likely to be a very good answer, and as such, deserves the default bounty. You can always reward your bounty manually.

Comment: I agree with one point which the per is price for the system to get more attention

Comment: If someone told you "You don't need to fix it"  and he was upvoted. 
the situation I have mentioned was Hypothesis , and i will keep it in mind

Comment: @MoathHowari so the protection you are referring to is not about getting your rep back, it is about preventing the auto award to a specific answer?

Comment: @psubsee2003 not preventing just adding some protection so  it goes harder to gain.